# Teamcity doesnt trigger build on non-default branches for pending changes

Tags: git, teamcity

I have three branches:

1. refs/heads/dev (default)
2. refs/headsrelease
3. refs/heads/master

Have added VCS and schedule trigger for two different Build configuration. However when changes are committed to one of three, by default build triggers only for **dev**.

VCS Trigger screenshot:

[image]

Schedule Trigger screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Please help.

We are using Teamcity 10.x version

Comment: Check that you set branches in `Branch specification` for VSC options.

Comment: i have set branches in VCS otpions default and other two in branch specs

Comment: Okay, let try to remove `Branch Filter` from trigger. It means that trigger would be invoked by changing from `Branch specification` of VCS.

Comment: tried removing branch filter it doesnt trigger, but if i put +:* it triggers on default branch which doesnt have any change, but shows pending change on non-default branch

Comment: we dont directly checkin to release but via Pull Request from feature branch